# ImportError when starting django server on centos

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I have installed python `virtualenv` and `django` on my virtual private server running over CentOS 6.5.

Assigned python version 2.7 alias for `python` command
(*because I have python 2.6.6 installed previously*).

Then I run:

```
django-admin startproject 
mysite cd mysite
```

After django creates new project, I try to run web-server by typing
`python2 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`

When I try to connect to website it shows me *`ERR_CONNECTION_TIME_OUT`* error in my browser.

Have checked whether my firewall is blocking this port or not, it doesn't.

When I type `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` (difference from previous call is that I call python, not python2)

it shows me this output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ImportError: No module named django.core.management
```

What would be solution for this problem?

Comment: did you actually use the virtualenv? which env did you installed Django in?

Comment: @NikosVitaTopiko I've installed and switched to my python2.7 virtualenv, tried installing django in there. Everything seems to be okay, but when I type `python -> import django` it show me the same output `ImportError`. I think somehow django is being installed in python2.6

Comment: i think you messed up setting an alias. If on your command promt there is the virtualenv name like (ENV)$ then you can pip install django and theny python --> import django

Comment: You can install Django in as many virtualenv's as you like. So to install django in the python2.7 env, just type **pip install django** when your virtualenv is active

Comment: Just type `which python` in your virtual environment (activate it with source command) and it should show you path of the python inside your virtual environment folder, not in the system. If it is inside of your virtualenv folder then type `python`, then `import django` and `django.__file__` and it should show path for django plugin again inside virtual environment folder. Now, did you had any problem with these instructions and if so, where? That will help to solve problem.